# call a ASP.net web API restful put method from R and pass in a custom object

Tags: c#, r, curl, asp.net-web-api, rcurl

I am trying to invoke a C# restful service's PUT method. The signature is as below:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutAccount(string custID, Account acc)
{

}
```

I am calling this method from in R using RCurl and rjson using:

```
account<- list(
    AccountBalance = 0, 
    MetaInfo = list("type=savings&branchCode=343")
    )

putUrl<-"http://localhost:9000/api/account?custid=123"

httpPUT(putUrl, toJSON(account))
```

The issue is the account object in put method is always received as null. 
Any ideas as to how to call a ASP.net web API restful put method from R and pass in a custom object?

Comment: You have `tosJSON`...do you want `toJSON`? And what package is `toJSON` coming from?

Comment: yes it is toJSON. The package name has been mentioned in the details above(rjson)